# How to hide an element in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I want to hide an element based in a condition,
This is what i do:
First i use a v-if with computed property, but is not working, because when HMR reload the page, the button is hidden. And when i logout and login and refresh the localSorage with other condition, the button is still hidden or vice versa, the button is shown where should not.
 Why? 
This is my code:

```
computed:{
    RegistrarUsuario(){
        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
        var acciones = userData.info.Acciones
        for(var i = 0; i < acciones.length; i++){
            if(acciones[i].accion === 'RegistrarUsuario'){                    
                return false;                                   
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }                
        }               
    }
},

<v-btn v-if="RegistrarUsuario" slot="activator" dark>Agregar</v-btn>
```

Comment: @DigitalDrifter i change the computed with a method and use a data() { return {}} variable, and then call the method in created() but still not working

Comment: i think the problem inside the function logic

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim in console i sow if 'RegistrarUsuario' is found or not, this is working, but in vue is not working this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only looking at the first element of your `acciones` array (you return true or false on the first iteration).  I suspect what you want is to return false if any of the elements matches.  To do this you could use Array.some():

```
RegistrarUsuario(){
    var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("usuario"));
    var acciones = userData.info.Acciones

    return !acciones.some(a => a.accion === 'RegistrarUsuario');                   
}
```